# Any way to dynamically alter function args within class method?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am looking for some kind of design pattern, pattern in general, or preferably a pythonic way to handle the following issue. Suppose we have a `SuperCalculator` class that performs some very complex calculations and then validates it with some metrics that `defaultvalidator` handles by default.

```
class SuperCalculator:

    validator = defaultvalidator

    def do_complex_calculation(self):
        # here we do some static but complex calculations

        # arg1 and arg2 are baked into `do_complex_calculation`'s
        # call of `self.validator`
        if self.validator(arg1, arg2):
            return calculation 
        else:
            raise SuperCalculatorExc()
```

Now assume the client wants to dynamically change the validator to use completely different metrics, including different args passed into the validation process. Or even if the client wanted to extend `SuperCalculator`, how can they make similar changes without making them override `do_complex_calculations`?

```
sc = SuperCalculator()
sc.validator = customvalidator
sc.do_complex_calculation()
```

The issue here is that `do_complex_calculation` has `arg1`, `arg2` baked into its call of  `self.validator`. Is there a design pattern that will help solve this issue? I've had trouble researching this and would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: The fact is the arguments passed in the call to `validator ()` *must* be hardcoded — what you're calling "baked" — into the `do_complex_calculation()` function. While there certainly are ways to pass a variable number of arguments to a function using `*args` syntax, that doesn't help because the calling function, `do_complex_calculation()`, still has to pass them, whatever they are— so, no, there's no :pattern" do what you want generically.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand by the description of your problem is the need for a variable number of arguments. It's a widely used pattern in python and is very simple.

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)
```

```
>>> foo()
()
>>> foo(1)
(1,)
>>> foo(1, 2)
(1, 2)
>>> foo(1, 2, 'string')
(1, 2, 'string')
```

`args` is a `tuple` containing the positional arguments passed to `foo`. Now, we have to pass them to your validator.

```
def do_complex_calculation(self, *args):
    # complex calculation here
    if self.validator(*args):  # simply unpack args and pass it to validator
        return calculation 
    else:
        raise SuperCalculatorExc()
```

---

I would suggest you to read about a few topics

- * as an unpack operator (not multiply)
- *args in a function parameter
- ** as an unpack operator (dict unpacking, not power)
- **kwargs in a function parameter

If you want more modifications with them, you can also read about,

- positional only arguments
- keyword only arguments

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am already aware of the unpacking operators and you're completely correct in that they work in this case. However, I assumed there was an API cost to incorporating them, because then the client would have to make sure to pass in the args. I was mainly inquiring as to whether there was a better way to handle an issue of this sort through some type of design pattern - something like a decorator, that would allow dynamic changes or easy extension/overriding etc. Thanks though!